# Problems with 0s when centering a dummy variable within cluster

Tags: multilevel-analysis, centering

Supposing that I have a set of data that is structured like this:

| customerID | orderID | couponUse | purchaseQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1a | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1b | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1c | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2a | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2b | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3a | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 3b | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 3c | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 3d | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5000 | 5000a | 0 | 2 |

where customerID is the unique ID of a customer; purchaseID is the unique ID of each purchase; and couponUse is a binary variable with 1 representing "used coupon" and 0 representing "coupon not used".

I wish to find out how couponUse could affect purchaseQuantity, so I conducted multilevel modeling on the data. However, when centering couponUse, I run into this problem: for customer #2 or #3, for example, they always used coupons (couponUse =1). When centering this variable within cluster (customer), that is, centering within group means, couponUse for customer #2 and 3 will be all 0s. I am assuming this will greatly distort the coefficient for *couponUse*, if there are many customers who always used coupons.

My understanding is that:
$$purchaseQuantity_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1j} * couponUse_{ij} + r_{ij}$$
for group j (that is, $customer_j$), when $couponUse_{ij} = 0$, $\beta_{1j}$ would be ignored.

Am I right to assume that centering within cluster would not be appropriate for this model? What if I wish to separate the effect of couponUse from other predictors or the random effect introduced by sampling?

Thank you!